# how to Session sharing asp.net to mvc ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, share

how to Session sharing asp.net to mvc ?

I tried this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27090/Sharing-Session-Across-Applications , but It didnt work

Comment: Are you still going to be within the same website but different virtual folders or are you going to completely different hosts?

Comment: for example xxx.com to aaa.com and different host

Comment: Yeah are you navigating from abc.com/asp to abc.com/mvc or as you said xxx.com to aaa.com

Comment: There are a lot of variables that could influence your approach to this. One way i have seen is to transfer the session from one site to another by serialising it and posting it over to the target. the target would then deserialise it and save it into session. If you are on the same server you might be able to make it use the same session it really depends on your setup.